# Unable to delete eSIM profile on Google Pixel 3a

Tags: android, sim-card, google-pixel, e-sim

I have recently changed phone carriers. I cannot download an eSIM for my new carrier while it is supposed to be compatible with the Pixel 3a. They claim this is because I still have the eSIM profile from my previous carrier. For some reason, I cannot erase this old eSIM profile manually. I get the following error message: “Can't erase SIM. This SIM can't be erased due to an error. Restart your device and try again.” Of course, I still can't erase the eSIM when I restart the phone.

I have contacted both carriers, as well as Google. They had me reset Wi-Fi, mobile & Bluetooth which didn't work. The next step they advise is a factory reset. I'd like to find another way to erase this faulty eSIM profile and I'm not completely sure that a factory reset would be “strong enough” actually.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem or knows a way to force the deletion of the old eSIM profile?

Comment: Try https://android.stackexchange.com, as this is not a programming question.

Comment: Will do, sorry for posting that in the wrong community

Comment: @Sennin Did you solve this issue? I have the same.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. It seems to be a somewhat common issue, and I contacted Google multiple times but they haven't been of any help

Answer (score 0):

did you active Google Fi on your device? If you did, clear all data and catches from it, uninstall the esim manager app, and restart your device, then hopefully it will work well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).